# How to pass a parameter in Pentaho Carte executeJob?

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I need to pass a parameter via an url.

This URL is working:

http://cluster:cluser@127.0.0.1:8081/kettle/executeJob/?job=/opt/pentaho/INSERT_VALUTA.kjb

The job gets executed. But now I need to pass a parameter.

The parameter name is: VALUTA_DATE

The value is like this: 2019-09-01

How do I do it?

This doesnt work:

http://cluster:cluser@127.0.0.1:8081/kettle/executeJob/?job=/opt/pentaho/INSERT_VALUTA.kjb&paramVALUTA_DATE=2019-09-01

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Here is the hint that it works in general:
https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-2663

The named parameter  needs be send via POST method:

wget --no-proxy http://cluster:cluster@127.0.0.1:8099/kettle/executeJob/?job=/opt/pentaho/INSERT_VALUTA.kjb --post-data "VALUTA_DATE=2019-08-08"

If you need more than one parameter:

--post-data "VALUTA_DATE=2019-08-08&TYPE=1&MORE=XYZ"

The same applies for transformations and variables.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work in curl:

curl -L -X POST --basic --user 'user:password' 'http://12.34.56.789:9000/kettle/executeTrans/?rep=&trans=/my/remote/path/SmokeTest.ktr&filenamepath=/my/remote/path/myTemp&index=pi314159265358'

Where:

1. 12.34.56.789:9000 is my remote ipaddress and port (where carte is running),
2. rep is my non-existent repo (the url parameter is always required, even if it is blank, as it is in my case).
3. trans is the full path (on the remote
   machine) of my transformation file SmokeTest.ktr;
4. My first parameter filenamepath is where my SmokeTest.ktr file writes
   a txt file (Pentaho adds the .txt), and
5. My second parameter index is the text (along with other stuff) that is written into that txt file.

Note that the order seemed important (I couldn't put rep anywhere except the beginning, which doesn't make sense to me.).

The result on the remote Linux box (that is running Carte):

[tihamer@ServerName project]$ more tmp/myTemp.txt
Gettysburg;comment;Count;filenamepath;index
Four score and seven years ago, our forefathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.;"Pass Parameters in during the ""Get variables""step.";2.71828;/my/remote/path/myTemp;pi314159265358
[tihamer@ServerName project]$

Note that most of temporary file's contents is dependent on how I configured the steps in SmokeTest.ktr.

The nice thing about running ktr files this way is that my Kettle PDI Status page at http://12.34.56.789:9000/kettle/status/ gives me access to the log and lots of other useful info.

The official documentation at https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.3/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/020 gave me a few clues, but some examples would have saved me a lot of frustrating experimentation.

BTW, one of the experiments I did (on the Carte server running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9) was to make sure that Pentaho was working correctly:

1. panHome=/path/data-integration
2. basepath=/pathTo/myproject
3. filenamepath=/pathTo/myproject/tmp/thisGettysburg.tmp
4. $panHome/pan.sh "-param:base.dir=$basepath" "-param:filenamepath=$filenamepath" "-param:index=$index"-rep: -file=$basepath/etl/SmokeTest.ktr